# $\int \frac{\ln(1-\sin(2x))}{\sin(2x)}\, dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, polylogarithm

$$\int \frac{\ln(1-\sin(2x))}{\sin(2x)}\,\mathrm{d}x$$

I tried to find the solution through WolframAlpha and I got the result, but I do not know how the solution is:
$$1/2 (2 \operatorname{Li}_2(1 - \tan(x)) + \operatorname{Li}_2(-i \tan(x)) + \operatorname{Li}_2(i \tan(x)) + \log(1 - i \tan(x)) \log(\tan(x)) + \log(1 + i \tan(x)) \log(\tan(x)) + \log(1 - \sin(2 x)) \log(\tan(x))) + \operatorname{const.}$$

Comment: Are you familiar with the [dilogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence's_function) $\operatorname{Li_{2}}$?

Comment: @creedoos If my answer has helped you, I'd appreciate a checkmark :)

Answer (score 4):

**We want to prove that**
$$I := {\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\ln\left(1-2\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{\sin\left(2x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x = -\dfrac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(2\sin\left(x\right)-1\right)}{4}-\dfrac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(2\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{2}-\dfrac{\ln\left(1-2\sin\left(x\right)\right)\ln\left(2-2\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{4}-\dfrac{\ln\left(3\right)\ln\left(-2\sin\left(x\right)-2\right)}{4}+\dfrac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{-2\sin\left(x\right)-2}{3}\right)}{4}.$$

## Rewrite

$$={\displaystyle\int}-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-1}{2\cos\left(x\right)}}\cdot\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-2}{\dfrac{\ln\left(1-2\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{\left(-2\sin\left(x\right)-2\right)\left(2-2\sin\left(x\right)\right)\sin\left(x\right)}}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
With the substitution $u=1-2\sin(x)$ we get to
$$-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-3}{2}}{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\ln\left(u\right)}{\left(u-3\right)\left(u-1\right)\left(u+1\right)}\,\mathrm{d}u.$$
By using partial fraction decomposition
$$\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-4}{\dfrac{1}{8}}}\underbrace{\int\dfrac{\ln\left(u\right)}{u+1}\,\mathrm{d}u}_{I_1}-\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-5}{\dfrac{1}{4}}}\underbrace{{\int}\dfrac{\ln\left(u\right)}{u-1}\,\mathrm{d}u}_{I_2}+\class{steps-node}{\cssId{steps-node-6}{\dfrac{1}{8}}}\underbrace{{\int}\dfrac{\ln\left(u\right)}{u-3}\,\mathrm{d}u}_{I_3}.$$

## $I_1$

Partial integration yields
$$I_1=\ln\left(u\right)\ln\left(u+1\right)-{\displaystyle\int}\dfrac{\ln\left(u+1\right)}{u}\,\mathrm{d}u$$
If you substitute $v=-u$ in the integral, this is equal to $\operatorname{Li_2}(v)$. Substituting back yields
$$I_1=\ln\left(u\right)\ln\left(u+1\right)+\operatorname{Li_2}(-u).$$

## $I_2$

Substitute $v=u-1$. This will get us to a very similar integral we calculated in $I_1$. In conclusion
$$\operatorname{Li_2}(1-u)$$

## $I_3$

After substituting $v=u-3$:
$$I_3={\displaystyle\int}\left(\dfrac{\ln\left(\frac{v}{3}+1\right)}{v}+\dfrac{\ln\left(3\right)}{v}\right)\mathrm{d}v$$
We can split the integral up. The first integral can be evaluated with the same methods as earlier. This will yields $-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\dfrac{v}{3}\right)$. The second integral easily evaluates to $\ln 3\ln v$.
$$I_3=\ln\left(3\right)\ln\left(u-3\right)-\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\dfrac{u-3}{3}\right).$$

## $I$

Putting all of the above together:
$$I=-2\left(\dfrac{\ln\left(u\right)\ln\left(u+1\right)}{8}+\dfrac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-u\right)}{8}+\dfrac{\ln\left(3\right)\ln\left(u-3\right)}{8}-\dfrac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{u-3}{3}\right)}{8}+\dfrac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(1-u\right)}{4}\right).$$
Now remember $u=1-2\sin x$.

$$I=-\dfrac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(2\sin\left(x\right)-1\right)}{4}-\dfrac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(2\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{2}-\dfrac{\ln\left(1-2\sin\left(x\right)\right)\ln\left(2-2\sin\left(x\right)\right)}{4}-\dfrac{\ln\left(3\right)\ln\left(-2\sin\left(x\right)-2\right)}{4}+\dfrac{\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-\frac{-2\sin\left(x\right)-2}{3}\right)}{4}.$$